# strange gdbserver output shows at my target device

Tags: gdb, stderr, gdbserver, error-suppression, uclinux

when I run gdbserver on uclinux target device blackfin bfin537/stamp it work perfectly but it always generates annoying output 
Request to get for unknown register 232
Request to get for unknown register 236

it is extremely annoying since each step out or step in gdb client results several of that error on the output screen terminal RS232 I was recommended to change the bfin compiler  version and rebuild gdb server with different version of uclinux ,.... none of them worked and even compiling my code with different versions of bfin-uclinux-gcc didn't solve my problem.

I decided to recompile gdbserver.c and eliminate the line that generates the error but in fact that line does not exists in any of the gdbserver related files for compiling.

I decided to suppress the stderr output of gdb server by running gdbserver :3298 process 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null but this didn't solve it 
how can I configure my gdb client to asks for specific registers (bfin-uclinux-gdb) related to bfin537-stamp?

I think this error originates somewhere else in uclinux system background system processes.
I want to find which process writes in stderr,stdout which I am unaware of It and I want to suppress its outputs?

Shall I change something in the busybox shell or /bin/bash to eliminates all stderr outputs
which means if I send all the parent shell output or stderr to /dev/null
Thanks